# Left Join not displaying missing records

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables tbl_data and tbl_events.

The table tbl_data has various events organized in a site. the columns will be SiteNo, EventName and EventDate. Each event performed in the site will be recorded in this table along with the eventdate.

The tbl_events table is a lookup table containing all the events that may happen in the site.

Some sites may have some events done and some events will be yet to done. I want the list of events that are pending for the sites.

I used left outer join and left join to combine the tbl_data and the tbl_events table however i' getting only the list of events happened. However i want to find the missing or pending ones for the sites.

Below is my sql code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SiteID
       ,le.eventname
       ,eventdate
    FROM lu_events AS le
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SiteID
                       ,e.eventname
                       ,d.eventdate
                    FROM tbl_data d
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN lu_events e ON d.eventname = e.eventname
               ) AS Grp ON Grp.eventname = le.eventname;
```

This is my output for the above sql query

[image: Output]

However I need all the missing rows in my output so that i can get a count of how many events are pending.

Below is my required output.

[image]

I tried a lot but unable to get the above output.

Here is my db Script. I faced some problem in the sql fiddle. so uploaded it to my onedrive.

[Sql Script](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8A7B9CB885EB9ED3!1271&authkey=!AL3rteKiWUkho00&ithint=file%2Csql)

Comment: Maybe you want `d.eventname` not  `e.eventname`in your inner select. `e.eventname` will be NULL for a missing record and obviously won't join to `lu_events`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a table that contains one record for each siteId in tbl_data. This is done by grouping on siteID
2. Cross join that table with the table containing all events (lu_events). You will then have a result table containing all combinations of siteId and eventName
3. Join that table with the events in tbl_data using a left outer join so you will also get the combinations of siteId and eventName that don't have a record in tbl_data

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT d.siteid
           ,e.EventName
        FROM ( SELECT e.siteid
                FROM tbl_data e
                GROUP BY e.SiteID
             ) d
        CROSS JOIN lu_events e
     ) tab
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_data d ON d.EventName = tab.EventName
                              AND d.SiteID = tab.SiteID
ORDER BY tab.SiteID
```

Albert